# Fixed Header Auto-Sized

Tags: html, css

I have a situation where I need a fixed/frozen page header of variable size, where the rest of the page can scroll.

If I use `position: fixed` on the header, my content overlaps the header.  If I fix the position and sizes of both the header and content, the two areas can overlap (or not be adjacent) based on the size of the head (which as I said, can change).

Currently the page has a `<div>` header and a `<table>` where the content is.

Comment: Do you have a code example?

Comment: @PhilSandler you can take one <table> with Two rows <tr> with one column <td>. In first row's <td> take <Div> for header with fixed width. in second row take another div with some properties like this... <div style="**overflow:auto; hight:400px; width:500px**"> .

Answer (score 0):

if you have a header and content div, eg:

```
<div id=header></div>
<div id=content></div>
```

You need to style the content with `margin-top: (whatever your header height is);`

Also you need to give a `position: relative;` to your content div as well as `z-index` on both. Higher number `z-index` for the header and lower for the content.